# "years to complete" vs. "years in which to complete"

Tags: differences

My personal tutor has a PhD in linguistics. She emailed me

> I am sorry to hear of your mental illness. You are reminded to read [the Quality Manual](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/qualitymanual/registration-and-attendance/max-period-from-initial-registration.aspx), in case you require an extension to the normal 6 years **in which [emphasis mine]** to complete your programme.

What changes, if anything, if you omit **in which**? Is **in which** redundant?

I read [Aharon's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/403265) that "**in which**" cannot always be omitted.

Comment: "the normal 6 years to complete your program" could mean it normally takes six years to complete, "the normal 6 years in which to complete your program" means it must be completed within 6 years but not necessarily take all that time. (As this is just based on my intuition as an English speaker, I'm not sure how to turn this into an answer with references and other apparatus.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of "in which" clarifies that six years is the normal span of time allowed for program completion rather than the amount of time it typically takes for a student to complete the program.